# Seaborn stripplot doesn't show the facecolor with only 3 records

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

**Explanation:**

I am making a plot with `stripplot` method using hue argument, but some markers of the result image didn't have face colors I intended, instead they have black, gray or white.

The simplified code below makes a image alike in my case. There are only 3 records to plot, and their markers lose face colors.

[image: the created plot]

I am new in Python, so I might miss something... If this post needs more info, please tell me.

**Question:**

Is there any work around that the only 3 record have face color?

**Environment:**

- MacOS 10.11.1
- Python 2.7.10 (Homebrew install)
- seaborn 0.6.0 (pip install)
- matplotlib 1.5.0 (pip install)

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("tips")
data = data[data.sex == "Female"][0:3]

plot = sns.stripplot(
    x="total_bill",
    y="sex", 
    data=data
    )

plt.show()
```

Comment: this looks like a bug to me... unless there's some hidden feature I'm missing

Comment: See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/753

Comment: Thank you tom for embedding the image.
Thank you mwaskom and I follow that work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been already referred on GitHub.

See [github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/753](http://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/753)